# Fragment из card view в scrollview

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-scrollview, fragment-manager

Имеется fragment который построен на cardview
В activity есть только toolbar с кнопкой +, и после тулбара идёт пустой scroolview который содержит контейнер для fragment.
Поделитесь пожалуйста частью рабочего кода который при нажатии на плюс будет добавлять новый fragment на основе cardview в scrollview в activity
Сейчас получается добавлять только первый элемент, при нажатии повторно на плюс, добавляется поверх первого второй элемент, как добавить fragment после первого существующего и чтоб все они были как бы один под другим?
Соответственно для этого и есть scrollview который должен пролистывать все фрагменты, которые как бы находятся в списке.
Огромное спасибо

Comment: Моя проблема в том что при добавлении нового фрагмента он тупо перекрывает уже существующий

Comment: Вам надо бы, наверное, пересмотреть своё решение вашей задачи. Даже если мы вам покажем как сделать то, что вы хотите, то вы столкнётесь с тем, что при добавлении некоторого кол-ва фрагментов у вас приложение просто упадёт из-за нехватки памяти. Скорее всего вам надо вместо фрагмента создать кастомную вьюху и отображать её экземпляры в RecyclerView. Такой способ избавит вас от падений из-за памяти, т.к. невидимые в данный момент вьюхи будут автоматически выгружаться из оперативной памяти.

Comment: Если же фрагментов у вас ожидается не очень много (хз сколько, ибо зависит от того что в них, пусть будет 10) то, наверное, можно и ваше решение применить. И тогда вам надо будет просто для каждого фрагмента создать отдельный контейнер внутри вьюхи, которая внутри ScrollView

Comment: Ну, попробуйте тогда решение из моего второго коммента. Хотя всё же подумайте над отказом от фрагментов в данном случае, т.к. решение странновато и может принести проблемм.

Comment: У меня будут немного фрагментов, максимум 20, которые влезут в два полных экрана, но точное количество знать не могу, пользователь динамически будет их добавлять и удалять кнопкой плюс И кнопочкой удалить на самом фрагменте

Comment: Можно пожалуйста кусок примера кода ?

Comment: С кнопкой удаления на фрагменте - замучаетесь. Придётся помимо фрагмента ещё и его контейнер удалять. Не очень понимаю, какой код вам показать. У вас уже есть код добавления фрагмента. Если вы хотите всё же оставить фрагменты, то вам надо менять разметку, программно в разметку добавлять контейнеры для фрагментов, программно им ID уникальные назначать и потом всё это ещё корректно удалять, что очень нетривиально. Лучше на RecyclerView и кастомные вьюхи переделайте - там все эти операции сделаны уже, да к тому же оптимизировано всё по памяти.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь буду гуглить что такое recyclerview как им пользоваться и как делать кастомною вьюху. Думал что фрагменты это лучшее решение но ошибся благодарю!